# performant css with polymer, or custom elements in general

Tags: css, polymer

With Polymer (or custom elements in general), I've seen most examples use a separate `<link>` element in each element to style it, but this clearly doesn't scale. What's the usual way to deal with this? Can you just have 1, or a small number of css files, referencing the same file in multiple element definitions?

Comment: That should be no problem. I typically have a common.css file elements re-use with colors, fonts, etc. in side. Then define another specific stylesheet or inline `<style>`s that the element needs. By the way, in Chrome 36, stylesheets are cached/shared by elements. That is, if element-a and element-b reference the same stylesheet, there should be little to no overhead.